# Coordinate Geometry

Tags: geometry

If the points $A(1,-2), B(2,3), C(-3,2)$ and $D(-4,-3)$ are the vertices of parallelogram $ABCD$, then taking $AB$ as the base, find the height of this parallelogram.

Comment: OK, I found it. Now what?

Comment: then what's the height?

Comment: @Learner You should ask a question, like `How can I finde the heigth`, tell us what you have tried, did you make a skech ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis this question was asked in my exam, and i wasn't able to understand how to approach to answer? it was suppose to answer with distance formula √(x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2 or area of triangle 1/2[x1(y2-y3)+x2(y3-y1)+x3(y1-y2) or section formula?
it would be great if you could tell me?

Comment: Since you have a formula for the area of a triangle in terms of its vertices, and since you also know that the area is half the height times the base, and since you know the base, you can put it all together to find the height, as in the answer by @Banerjee.

Comment: i got my answer as 5 units is that right?

Comment: @user65345: This contradicts the computed answers below. How did you get $5$?

Answer (score 3):

The equation of $AB$ : $$\frac{y-3}{x-2}=\frac{3-(-2)}{2-1}\implies 5x-y-7=0$$

So, the height will be the perpendicular distance of $AB$ from $C(-3,2)$ or $D(-4,-3)$

$$\left|\frac{5(-3)-(2)-7}{\sqrt{5^2+1^2}}\right|=\frac{24}{\sqrt{26}}\text{ or }\left|\frac{5(-4)-(-3)-7}{\sqrt{5^2+1^2}}\right|=\frac{24}{\sqrt{26}}$$

---

Let us calculate the perpendicular distance of $AB$ from any point on the line CD:

The equation of $CD$ : $$\frac{y-(-3)}{x-(-4)}=\frac{-3-2}{-4-(-3)}\implies y=5x+17$$

If $h$ is the abscissa of any point $P$ on CD, the ordinate will be $y=5h+17$

So, the perpendicular distance of $AB$ from any point $P(h,5h+17)$ on $CD$ will be

$$\left|\frac{5(h)-(5h+17)-7}{\sqrt{5^2+1^2}}\right|=\frac{24}{\sqrt{26}}$$

So, the perpendicular distance of $AB$ from any point on the line $CD$ is independent of $h$ hence, constant (Why ? Because $AB || CD$ )

For $h=-4,P(h,5h+17)$ becomes $D(-4,-3)$ and for $h=-3,P$ becomes $C$

Comment: i wonder if OP knows about equation of line and the distance formula you have used to calculate distance of a point from a line.

Comment: @Avatar: this is a nice answer, and if the OP doesn't know yet, perhaps this will tempt them to learn. :-)

Comment: yeah, i agree with you on that.

Comment: @robjohn, thanks for your feedback. I didn't know the response on Avatar's question. Inspired by your response, I have added a little generalization to the answer:).

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved without finding the equation of the line. As area of ABCD=$AB\cdot $Height

Height$=\dfrac{2\cdot ar(ABC)}{AB}$

Comment: And how do you propose to find the area of the parallelogram (or the triangle)?

Comment: Using the formula written in one of the comments.

Comment: I see that my second answer uses this idea (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(x,y)\cdot(y,-x)=0$. Thus, $(x,y)$ is perpendicular to $(y,-x)$. Define $(x,y)^\perp=(y,-x)$.

$\overline{AB}=(1,5)$ and $\overline{BC}=(-5,-1)$. Thus, $\overline{AB}^\perp=(5,-1)$ and the height is given by
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left|\overline{AB}^\perp\cdot\overline{BC}\right|}{\left|\overline{AB}^\perp\right|}
&=\frac{|(5,-1)\cdot(-5,-1)|}{|(5,-1)|}\\
&=\frac{24}{\sqrt{26}}
\end{align}
$$

---

Let's use the tools mentioned in your comments. The parallelogram contains two equal triangles:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

The formula for the area of $\triangle BCD$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
|\triangle BCD|
&=\frac12\big[2(2-(-3))+(-3)(-3-3)+(-4)(3-2)\big]\\
&=12
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the area of the parallelogram is $2\cdot12=24$. The area of a parallelogram is the base times the height, and the base is $\left|\overline{AB}\right|=\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(3-(-2))^2}=\sqrt{26}$. Therefore
$$
\text{height}=\frac{24}{\sqrt{26}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Plotting it first, you can draw the height as you'd measure it, and then ask whether you can create the measurement apparatus you drew using information you see there.

I'm assuming by height they mean along the y-axis, not the lengths of the sides of the parallellogram.

So, the height can be any vertical cross-section, but the most convenient way to measure that seems to be to slide it to one of the points. From there, I drew a box around it and the nearest point on the x-axis. Then the problem comes down to eliminating the height of the line segment leaving the parallelogram from the height of the box.

But that's the opposite of a triangle similar to one you can make out of the vertices of the box, and you know the length of the adjacent, because the width of the box is just the difference of the points you drew it around along the x-axis. So you take the ratio of the height to the width on the large triangle made of the points on the parallelogram, and that ratio won't change when you rescale (or else what's the point of saying a line has a slope?), so you can just reinterpret that using the width of the box to recover the height of the small segment.

Comment: I don't think that "height" in this context refers to vertical cross-sections, but rather the length of a perpendicular from vertex $C$ or $D$ to the segment $AB$.

Comment: That's a vertical cross-section that meets one of the points C or D.

Comment: If $AB$ is not horizontal, then a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$ is not vertical, so I wouldn't call it a vertical cross-section.

Comment: If you mean a line perpendicular to AB, that has nothing to do with the reference frame, giving "height" two extra meanings. So you have to assume that the frame of mind someone's in when asking simply for "the height" is that they're looking at the plot of the quadrilateral on a horizontal-vertical grid and asking for the vertical cross-section.

Comment: The word "height" has an absolutely standard meaning in elementary plane geometry. Once you have decided to call one particular side of a triangle the "base", then the height of the triangle is the length of the perpendicular to that base from the opposite vertex, no matter what the orientation of the triangle with respect to any notions of vertical and horizontal. That's just the way the term "height" is used.

Comment: Pyramids, frusta, cones, cupolae have a face named the base. There's no one base for a parallelogram, cylinder, parallelepiped, pentagon, etc.. By calling a side of an polygon the base you invoke an image of that edge being horizontal and the rest of the polygon lying above it. It's standard imagery, not standard terminology, and that device conflicts with the actual polygon. I understand your interpretation of height here, it's just not the only one.

Comment: The problem says, **taking $AB$ as the base**. So there may be no one base for a parallelogram in general, but there sure as heck is one base for the parallelogram at issue! I'm confident that 99 mathematicians out of 100 would interpret "height" in this question the way I have done.

Comment: Right, and when I read that it only meant to me that since it's at an extreme on one axis, that's the axis of height. If it were a triangle, I'm sure I would treat it differently. Show me a paper that relies on assuming this interpretation when using coordinates or a picture and I'll believe it matters.

Comment: People don't write papers on parallelograms in coordinate geometry, so I don't think I'll be able to comply with your request. Also, I don't know what you mean by "it's at an extreme on one axis".

Comment: Each edge is an extreme in one of the two dimensions of the grid. So for a diamond, you could not call any edge the base as I used the term.

Comment: Not even if the person posing the problem selected on edge for you and told you that for the purposes of the problem that edge was to be taken as the base?

Comment: Because they used the term height, I know that means someone wants me to read their mind. But if a diamond was chosen, that would eliminate other suitable interpretations. So on the contrary, I would have decided on that meaning, and sooner.